# Android splash screen is shrunk

Tags: android, titanium

I have trouble with android splash screen.

I made splashscreen like these

```
/platform/android/res/drawable-hdpi/background.9.png
/platform/android/res/drawable-mdpi/background.9.png
/platform/android/res/drawable-xhdpi/background.9.png
/platform/android/res/drawable-xxhpi/background.9.png
/platform/android/res/drawable-xxxhdpi/background.9.png
```

These are made by [ticon](http://ticons.fokkezb.nl/) automatically.

and have confirmed these looks OK(correct background.9 below).

However, when I open appication (on Nexus7 2013),splashscreen looks much smaller.

I mean background.9.png are centered and there are white blank around image.

- correct [background.9](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/1320870/correct_background.9.png)
- shown [splashscreen](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/1320870/shown_background_9.png)

How can I adjust it to the screen???

Comment: Have you created layouts for large, xlarge screens?

Answer (score 0):

To adjust it to the screen, you just have to resize it accordingly and then create a drawable file like this for each screen size (this exemple will display a gradient background with an image in the center)

```
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">


<item>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <gradient
        android:startColor="#2b3143"
        android:centerColor="#37465e"
        android:endColor="#55647c"
        android:angle="135"/>
</shape>
</item>

<item>
    <bitmap
        android:gravity="center"
        android:src="@drawable/myCuteLogo"/>
</item>
```

You then create a style and set the property `android:windowBackground` with the drawable you created:

```
<style name="SplashScreenStyle" parent="myAppTheme">
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/splash_screen</item>
</style>
```

Then create a SplashActivity that will display the Splash screen:

```
public class SplashScreen extends AppCompatActivity {
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    Intent intent = new Intent(this, Activity_a_Main.class);
    startActivity(intent);
    finish();
}}
```

Lastly in your manifest set the SplashActivity as the Lancher activity and set its theme to the style you created:

```
<activity android:name=".Activities.SplashScreen"
        android:theme="@style/SplashScreenStyle">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

I hope this helps you

NOTE: If you set the style you created as the whole application's theme, it will show your drawable in weird places, like in the background of a soft keyboard

Comment: THanks for your answer, I am trying this and struggling for now.